# Convert for loop to forEach

Tags: javascript

I am creating a card game. I am trying to loop two arrays. I am able to do it with a `for` loop, but I want to use `forEach()`. I am not getting the right results. Below is the for loop that works, and then the `forEach()` way I've tried:

```
const suits = ['Heart','Diamond','Spade','Club']
const values=['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','K','Q','J','A']
const deck = []

for(i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
    for(x =0; x < suits.length; x++){
        const card = {value: values[i], suits: suits[x]}
        deck.push(card)
    }
}


values.forEach((value,x) => {
suits.forEach((suit,i) => {
   const card = {value: value[x], suits: suit[i]}
   deck.push(card)
})
})
```

Comment: The `value` parameter already contains the value from the array (same with the `suit` parameter); you don't need to index into the array at all.

Answer (score 3):

With your `forEach` you need not use index to access the value, you simply get the value from the argument for callback. However if you are using index, you need to access `values[x], suits[i]` instead of `value[x], suit[i]`.

```js
const suits = ['Heart','Diamond','Spade','Club']
const values=['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','K','Q','J','A']
const deck = [];
values.forEach((value,x) => {
suits.forEach((suit,i) => {
   const card = {value: value, suits: suit}
   deck.push(card)
})
})
console.log(deck)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps nicer than either a `for` loop or a `forEach` one is to use a technique designed to change one array into another, index by index, such as `map` or `flatMap`.

Here, creating the deck might be a one-liner:

```js
const suits = ['Heart','Diamond','Spade','Club']
const vals = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','K','Q','J','A']
const deck = vals .flatMap (value => suits .map (suit => ({value, suit}) ))


console .log (
  deck
)
```

Also note that there is a fairly strong tradition, at least in the U.S., of ordering the suits from low to high as "clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades".  In English this is easy to remember as they are sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration your arguments of forEach callbacks are ready to use in card object.

```
values.forEach(value => {
  suits.forEach(suit => {
    const card = { value, suits }
    deck.push(card)
  })
})
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `i` or `x` as `value`, `suit` have the values of each array

```js
const suits = ['Heart','Diamond','Spade','Club']
const values=['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','K','Q','J','A']
const deck = []


values.forEach((value) => {
  suits.forEach((suit) => {
     const card = {value: value, suits: suit}
     deck.push(card)
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(card) + "<br />"
  })
})
```

```html
<span id="content"></span>
```